# Cant access the page even after login in spring security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am building an app using Spring Security that has two roles: ADMIN and USER. However, even after logging in, I can access the admin page. I marked in `Config.java` that `/admin/**` is allowed, but this did not work. I am new to Spring Security and don't have enough knowledge about it.

`Controller.java`:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    @Autowired
    private Services services;

    @GetMapping("/admin/list")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public List<User> list(){
        return services.list();
    }


    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String login(@RequestBody Login login){
        return services.verify(login);
    }
    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public String userRegistration(@RequestBody User user){
        return services.userRegister(user);
    }

    @PostMapping("/admin/addcentre")
    public String addCentre(@RequestBody VaccinationCentre vc){
        return services.addCentre(vc);
    }
}
```

`Config.java`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MyConfig  {
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService getUserDetailServices() {
        return new UserDetailServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.getUserDetailServices());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                .requestMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
                .and().formLogin();

        httpSecurity.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        return httpSecurity.build();

    }


}
```

`UserDetailServiceImpl.java`:

```
public class UserDetailServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        System.out.println(email);
        User user=userRepository.findUserByUserEmail(email);
        if (user==null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No such user!!");
        }
        CustomUserDetails customUserDetails= new CustomUserDetails(user);
        return customUserDetails;
    }
}
```

`CustomUserDetails.java`:

```
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    private User user;

    public CustomUserDetails(User user) {
        super();
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        SimpleGrantedAuthority simpleGrantedAuthority=new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole());
        return List.of(simpleGrantedAuthority);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getUserPass();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUserEmail();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I also tried to use `@PreAuthorise`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Hello. It is a good practice to divide different files in different blocks. I've edited ur question (waiting 4 approval) and im'a bout to answer it, but first thing u need to do is to check whether adding prefix `ROLE_ ` in @PreAuthorize annotation will solve ur problem.